# Rust function to read the first line of a file, strip leading hashes and whitespace

Tags: beginner, io, rust

I’m writing a Rust function for getting a title based on the first line of a file.

The files are written in Markdown, and the first line should be a heading that starts with one or more hashes, followed by some text. Examples:

```
# This is a top-level heading
## This is a second-level heading
#### Let's jump straight to the fourth-level heading
```

I want to throw away the leading hashes, discard any leading/trailing whitespace, and return the remaining string. Example outputs:

```
"This is a top-level heading"
"This is a second-level heading"
"Let's jump straight to the fourth-level heading"
```

Assume that, for now, I’m not worried about edge cases like a first line that’s only whitespace and hashes, or a file whose first line is pathologically long.

---

This is the program I’ve written to do it:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::path::PathBuf;


/// Get the title of a Markdown file.
///
/// Reads the first line of a Markdown file, strips any hashes and
/// leading/trailing whitespace, and returns the title.    
fn title_string(path: PathBuf) -> String {

    // Read the first line of the file into `title`.
    let file = match fs::File::open(&path) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(_) => panic!("Unable to read title from {:?}", &path),
    };
    let mut buffer = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut first_line = String::new();
    let _ = buffer.read_line(&mut first_line);

    // Where do the leading hashes stop?
    let mut last_hash = 0;
    for (idx, c) in first_line.chars().enumerate() {
        if c != '#' {
            last_hash = idx;
            break
        }
    }

    // Trim the leading hashes and any whitespace
    let first_line: String = first_line.drain(last_hash..).collect();
    let first_line = String::from(first_line.trim());

    first_line
}


fn main() {
    let title = title_string(PathBuf::from("./example.md"));
    println!("The title is '{}'", title);
}
```

I’m fairly new to Rust, and I’m sure I’m doing stuff that isn’t as optimal or idiomatic as it could be.  Particular questions:

- Is this idiomatic Rust?
- Is there a better way to strip leading characters from a string? I looked in the documentation for [`std::string::String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html) and couldn’t see anything. The `String::from()` feels a bit inefficient.
- Is there anything unsafe that could easily crash (the `panic!` aside)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Clippy returns a helpful suggestion:

   > ```
   > warning: returning the result of a let binding from a block.
   >          Consider returning the expression directly.
   >          #[warn(let_and_return)] on by default
   >    |>
   >    |>     first_line
   >    |>     ^^^^^^^^^^
   > note: this expression can be directly returned
   >    |>
   >    |>     let first_line = String::from(first_line.trim());
   >    |>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   > ```
2. Don't ignore `Result`s by using `let _ =`! You should always return them or use `expect` or `unwrap`.
3. The loop could be simplified by using `take_while`:

   ```
   let last_hash = first_line.chars().take_while(|&c| c == '#').count();
   ```
4. **However**, treating one character as one byte is a bad idea because strings are UTF-8 encoded. UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. You can use `char_indices` instead.
5. It's slightly more efficient to take a slice of the string, instead of `drain` and `collect` here. It avoids one extra allocation.
6. Change your function to accept any type that implements `BufRead`; this will allow you to write easier unit tests.
7. Actually add those unit tests!
8. There's no need to create a `PathBuf`, you aren't pushing path components on. You could just make a `&Path`, but most functions accept any type that can be converted to a `Path` (`AsRef<Path>`). `&str` implements that.
9. There's no need to take a reference to something being passed to `println!` or `panic!`. These macros automatically take a reference.

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;

/// Get the title of a Markdown file.
///
/// Reads the first line of a Markdown file, strips any hashes and
/// leading/trailing whitespace, and returns the title.
fn title_string<R>(mut rdr: R) -> String
    where R: BufRead,
{
    let mut first_line = String::new();

    rdr.read_line(&mut first_line).expect("Unable to read line");

    // Where do the leading hashes stop?
    let last_hash = first_line
        .char_indices()
        .skip_while(|&(_, c)| c == '#')
        .next()
        .map_or(0, |(idx, _)| idx);

    // Trim the leading hashes and any whitespace
    first_line[last_hash..].trim().into()
}

/// Read the first line of the file into `title`.
fn main() {
    let path = "./example.md";

    let file = match fs::File::open(path) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(_) => panic!("Unable to read title from {}", path),
    };
    let buffer = BufReader::new(file);

    let title = title_string(buffer);

    println!("The title is '{}'", title);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::title_string;

    #[test]
    fn top_level_heading() {
        assert_eq!(title_string(b"# This is a top-level heading".as_ref()),
                   "This is a top-level heading")
    }

    #[test]
    fn second_level_heading() {
        assert_eq!(title_string(b"## This is a second-level heading".as_ref()),
                   "This is a second-level heading");
    }

    #[test]
    fn fourth_level_heading() {
        assert_eq!(title_string(b"#### Let's jump straight to the fourth-level heading".as_ref()),
                   "Let's jump straight to the fourth-level heading");
    }
}
```

You should also investigate using a real Markdown parser to avoid nasty pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! I’ve incorporated your suggestions, and fixed a bunch of other code at the same time. I’m using Hoedown to parse the Markdown properly – this function is just to give the files some human-readable names. :-)

Comment: @alexwlchan if you already are using a Markdown parser, can't you traverse the parsed file to find the first header and use that?

Comment: Yeah, that’s probably a better way to do it. I started with this function, and added the Markdown parser later – I should probably just scrap this function entirely, and use the parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

While [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135021/32521) covers most of the points, I noticed it doesn't bring up the very useful method `trim_matches` and `trim_left_matches`.

Your main string logic can then be simplified to:

```
fn trim(string: &str) -> &str {
    string.trim_left_matches('#').trim_matches(' ')
}
```